# Extending an object with a tree-traversing method in javascript

Tags: javascript, tree-traversal

I have a custom object that contains an array (called "children") where objects of the same type will be stored, in result creating a tree.
Let's say it looks like that:

```
function CustomObject(){
    if (this instanceof Topic) {
    this.text = "Test";
    this.children = [];
    } else
        return new CustomObject(); }
```

Now, I would like to add a "forAll" method to this object that would execute another function provided as an argument, on all elements of that tree in a depth-first fashion. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
CustomObject.prototype.forAll = function(func) {
  // process this object first
  func(this);

  // then process children
  for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++)
    this.children[i].forAll(func);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. It only seems to be executed on the first element and then exits with an error. It can be tried here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/118505/psychojs/p.html

Comment: @Piotr: Your error seems to be here: `map.centralTopic.forAll(get_text())` -- `get_text()` will call the function immediately, but you should be passing the function object to `forAll`, so you should do `map.centralTopic.forAll(get_text)`